# WiX Property ID Or Conditional Statement

Tags: wix

I need to create an install file that will check the registry for the version of another software.  Currently I'm commenting and un-commenting lines of code for separate installs.  How can I turn the below into an conditional?

```
<!--<Property Id="ACADREG" Value="ACAD-A001:409" /> Autocad 2012--> 
<Property Id="ACADREG" Value="ACAD-A004:409" /> <!--Autocad Arch 2012-->
```

I also need to obtain which version that is for later in the install.

```
    <Property Id="ACADROAMDIR">
    <RegistrySearch Id="ROAMROOTDIR" Root="HKCU" Type="raw" Key="Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\[ACADVER]\[ACADREG]" Name="RoamableRootFolder" />
    </Property>


    <Property Id="ACADDIR">
    <RegistrySearch Id="AcadLocRegistry" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\[ACADVER]\[ACADREG]" Name="AcadLocation" />
    </Property>
```

Is there a way wiX can set [ACADREG] by reading the registry instead of me setting it like I did above?

Comment: `<RegistrySearch>` element is used to read information from the registry. Then you can control which components, features, and actions are executed depending on the value of this property.

Comment: You can read registry for both the versions of software and provide a screen to the user to select one from them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm) condition:

```
<?define AutocadSku = "ACAD2012" ?>

<?if $(var.AutocadSku) = "ACAD2012" ?>
  <Property Id="ACADREG" Value="ACAD-A001:409" />
<?else?>
  <Property Id="ACADREG" Value="ACAD-A004:409" />
<?endif ?>
```

Or even better, the best practice is searching for both, so later on you could conditionally check for each property's existence or content:

```
<Property Id="ACADROAMROOTDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="ROAMROOTDIR" Root="HKCU" Type="raw" Key="Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.2\ACAD-A001:409" Name="RoamableRootFolder" />
</Property>
<Property Id="ACADROAMARCHROOTDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="ARCHROAMROOTDIR" Root="HKCU" Type="raw" Key="Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.2\ACAD-A004:409" Name="RoamableRootFolder" />
</Property>
```

Comment: This looks like I would still be creating two separate .msi packages.  I'm wanting to create one .msi file that will cater to both versions of AutoCAD.

Comment: No exactly, but it just forces you to maintain these properties. I think you shouldn't over-complicate it. I've updated my answer according to my understanding of your requirement.

Comment: This really isn't what I was looking for.  I've updated my post with what my code looks like.

Comment: How can I conditionally check for each property's content?

Comment: It depends... what do you intend to do with `ACADREG`? something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1215855/147211

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to redefine the property if the AutoCAD Arch 2012 is defined, otherwise use Autocad 2012.
I had a similar issue and I used the solution I found on this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690162/wix-set-a-property-based-on-a-condition)

```
<Property Id="ACADREG" Value="ACAD-A001:409" /> <!-- Autocad 2012--> 
<Property Id="ACADREG_ARCH" Value="ACAD-A004:409" /> <!--Autocad Arch 2012--> 


<Property Id="ACADROAMDIR">
<RegistrySearch Id="ROAMROOTDIR" Root="HKCU" Type="raw" Key="Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\[ACADVER]\[ACADREG]" Name="RoamableRootFolder" />
</Property>

<Property Id="ACADROAMDIR_ARCH">
<RegistrySearch Id="ROAMROOTDIR" Root="HKCU" Type="raw" Key="Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\[ACADVER]\[ACADREG_ARCH]" Name="RoamableRootFolder" />
</Property>

<Property Id="ACADDIR">
<RegistrySearch Id="AcadLocRegistry" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\[ACADVER]\[ACADREG]" Name="AcadLocation" />
</Property>

<Property Id="ACADDIR_ARCH">
<RegistrySearch Id="AcadLocRegistry" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\[ACADVER]\[ACADREG_ARCH]" Name="AcadLocation" />
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="ACADROAMDIR" After="AppSearch" Value="[ACADROAMDIR_ARCH]">
 ACADROAMDIR_ARCH
</SetProperty>

<SetProperty Id="ACADDIR" After="AppSearch" Value="[ACADDIR_ARCH]">
 ACADDIR_ARCH
</SetProperty>
```

After that, the properties you want will correctly be in ACADDIR and ACADROAMDIR